# Package 'thm-restate' breaks switching of theorem styles of 'ntheorem'

Tags: numbering, incompatibility, ntheorem, thmtools

I use `ntheorem` and define two theorem-like environments ("Theorem" and "Lemma") that share the same counter which is reset for every section. Moreover I have a proof-environment that has no counter at all.

At the same time I include `thm-restate` because I need to repeat a particular theorem.

Even if I do not use `thm-restate` but simply load the package, the lemma environment does not print its counter. If `thm-restate` is not loaded the output is as expected. Alternatively, if I omit switching the theorem style to `nonumberplain` for the proof-environment the counter is printed, too. However, in this case the proof gets numbered, too, which is not desired.

The MWE below yields

- List item
- Theorem 1.1
- Lemma
- Theorem 1.3
- Proof

expected output is

- Theorem 1.1
- Lemma 1.2
- Theorem 1.3
- Proof

This means, the shared counter is correctly incremented but not printed.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[thmmarks,thref]{ntheorem}
% Option 1: Either do no use 'thm-restate' and 'lemma' will be numbered
\usepackage{thm-restate}



\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\theoremseparator{}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont\itshape}
\theoremsymbol{}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
% Option 2: or do not use 'nonumberplain' and 'lemma' will be numbered
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\scshape}
\theoremseparator{}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}



\begin{document}

\section{Header}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.

\begin{theorem}[Suprising Result]
Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}[Trivial Conclusion]
Mauris ut leo.
Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem.
Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}[Awesome Result]
Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat.
Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc.
Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Aenean faucibus.
Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla.
Curabitur auctor semper nulla.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workaround. The definitions in the preamble needs to be re-ordered: first define theorem-like environments which are unnumbered and then the remaining one. However, this workaround only works if there is only one counter which is shared by all numbered theorem-like environments.

```
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\scshape}
\theoremseparator{}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\theoremseparator{}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont\itshape}
\theoremsymbol{}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `amsthm` rather than `ntheorem`. The `thmmarks` option applies several hacks in order to accomplish automatic marks (which don't always work, by the way). Using it just to define `proof` with the mark, is a waste, in my opinion.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thm-restate}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}


\begin{document}

\section{Header}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.

\begin{theorem}[Suprising Result]
Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}[Trivial Conclusion]
Mauris ut leo.
Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem.
Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.
\end{lemma}

\begin{restatable}[Awesome Result]{theorem}{awesome}
Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat.
Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc.
Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum.
\end{restatable}

\begin{proof}
Aenean faucibus.
Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla.
Curabitur auctor semper nulla.
\end{proof}

\awesome*

\end{document}
```

[image]